# How to troubleshoot 504 Gateway Timeout questions when using JFrog Artifactory on JFrog Cloud?

Tags: artifactory

I've been using JFrog Artifactory on JFrog Cloud for some time, and everything worked fine. For the past day, I've started getting a lot of **504 Gateway Timeout** responses from the Artifactory service when trying to download artifacts. This breaks CI/CD processes and prohibits developers from doing their job.

I looked at the service logs on the Artifactory UI, and nothing seems out of the ordinary there. Only successful requests and responses appear there. According to the [JFrog Cloud Status](https://status.jfrog.io/) page, all systems are operational, so there is no clue.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this issue via the web UI or the JFrog CLI? Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Edit: Some API requests from the web UI also receive a **504 Gateway Timeout**.

Comment: Hi Eran. Did it happen for a long period? What region and cloud provider? What subscription type are you using?

Comment: @EldadAssis I started seeing it more than 12 hours ago. We are using the Free Tier in Azure Australia.
I edited the question to add that we are also seeing some API requests from the Web UI returning a 504 error as well.

Comment: Will to DM you in another network for deeper analysis

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be a server-side issue on the Azure infrastructure that ran our Artifactory server. The JFrog team successfully resolved it.